# What do production game systems pack into the attribute fields in WebGL?

Tags: graphics, opengl-es, shader, webgl

It looks like you can pass in multiple things in the vertex buffer in addition to the position, such as color. What are a list of all the attributes used by production game systems in complex environments? What is a good example? Some things that come to mind:

- velocity/torque
- mass/density
- temp/energy
- emission/absorption

Is there a common set of things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though the per-vertex attributes are very game specific, I am listing down a few based on categories.

1. Geometric data

   - Position
   - Normals
   - Texture coordinates (multiple, based on number of textures)
   - Tangent, Bitagent (For normal map calculations)
   - Joint weight (joint id, weight)
   - Joint transform matrix (transformation matrix for joints)
   - level of details (tessellation)
2. Material data

   - Vertex color
   - reflection value
   - refraction value
   - Various light info (Emissive, ambient and other methods)
3. Physics data

   - mass / density
   - force
   - velocity
4. Particle data

   - index
   - age
   - lifetime
   - size
   - velocity
   - angular velocity

Please feel free to keep updating this space.

Answer (score 3):

There is no set of common things except positions, texture coordinates, and normals. Maybe also vertex colors, binormals and tangets. Otherwise everything else is game specific.

Most games don't use shaders for physics so velocity, torque, mass, density, temp, energy, emission, absorption, are not common inputs to a shader.